# Retrieving information from derived child object collections using LINQ

Tags: linq, collections, children

I have been trying to get a list of all Workflows that have Offices contained in a certain List by Office Id. I can easily get all of the Workflows that have SingleWorkflowSteps because they have only one Office, but have been unable to understand how I would successfully get those contained in a MultiWorkflowStep. All workflow steps have either a SingleWorkflowStep or a MultiWorkflowStep that contains two or more SingleWorkflowSteps. At the time I designed this, it seemed like a logical way to do this but atlas my LINQ-fu is not as good as I thought it was. Can someone please point me in the right directions. Code listed below:

```
var OfficesToFind = new List<int> (new int[] { 1,3,5,7,9,10,11,12} );


public class Workflow
{
    public Workflow()
    {
        WorkflowSteps = new List<WorkflowStepBase>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowStepBase> WorkflowSteps { get; set; }
}

public abstract class WorkflowStepBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual Workflow Workflow { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }        
}

public class MultiWorkflowStep : WorkflowStepBase
{
    public MultiWorkflowStep()
    {
        ChildSteps = new List<SingleWorkflowStep>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<SingleWorkflowStep> ChildSteps { get; set; }
}

public class SingleWorkflowStep : WorkflowStepBase
{
    public int? ParentStepId { get; set; }
    public int OfficeId { get; set; }

    public virtual MultiWorkflowStep ParentStep { get; set; }
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WorkflowService : IWorkflowService<Workflow>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Workflow> _workflowService;
    private readonly IRepository<SingleWorkflowStep> _singleStepService;
    private readonly IRepository<MultiWorkflowStep> _multiStepService;

    public WorkflowService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _workflowService = uow.GetRepository<Workflow>();
        _singleStepService = uow.GetRepository<SingleWorkflowStep>();
        _multiStepSercice = uow.GetRepository<MultiWorkflowStep>();
    }

    // ~ ------- Other CRUD methods here -------- ~

    public IEnumerable<Workflow> GetWorkflowFilter(List<int> statuses, List<int> offices...)
    {
        var query = _workflowService.GetIQueryable(); // returns an IQueryable of dbset

        if(statuses.Any())
        {
            query = query.Where(q => statuses.Contains(q.StatusId));
        }

        if(offices.Any())
        {
            // Get all active single steps and the ones that contain the offices
            singleSteps = _singleStepService
                .Where(s => s.StatusId == (int)Enumerations.StepStatus.ACTIVE)
                .Where(s => offices.Contains(s.OfficeId));  

            // Get all of the parent Workflows for the singleSteps
            var workflows = singleSteps.Select(w => w.Workflow);

            // Update the query with the limited scope
            query = query.Where(q => q.Workflow.Contains(q));
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your Linq look like for the case you know how to do?

Comment: I updated my original post with the code for the service call that includes the Linq for the SingleWorkflowStep as per your comment. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks @JesanFafon for your comment, oddly enough, it was enough to fire up the old synchros and servos to get my head wrapped around the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a good night sleep, being all bright-eyed and bushy-tailed, I figured out my own problem. First the updated code was all wrong. Because each derived WorkflowStep has access to the Workflow and each MultiWorkflowStep contains a list of SingleWorkflowSteps - when I get the list of all SingleWorkflowSteps (which would include all from MultiWorkflowStep(s)), I simply needed to get a list of all of the parent Workflows of the SingleWorkflowSteps. Next I updated my query to limit the Workflows that were contained in the new Workflow list and here is the correct code for the GetWorkflowFilter method:

```
...
    if(offices.Any())
    {
        // Get all active single steps and the ones that contain the offices
        singleSteps = _singleStepService.Where(s => s.StatusId == (int)Enumerations.StepStatus.ACTIVE).Where(s => offices.Contains(s.OfficeId));  

        // Get all of the parent Workflows for the singleSteps
        var workflows = singleSteps.Select(w => w.Workflow);

        // Update the query with the limited scope
        query = query.Where(q => q.Workflow.Contains(q));
    }
    return query.ToList();
}
```